# database connection auto closed after the connection variable is not reachable in python

Tags: python

My memory is that after used a connection we need to close it. But I found an interesting thing that when a connection variable is not reachable, then looks like the connection is auto close.

```
import MySQLdb
import time

def get_mysql_connection():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                         user="test",
                         passwd="test",
                         db="test")
    db.autocommit = True
    return db


for _ in range(1,100):
    print "get connection"
    a = get_mysql_connection()
    print id(a)
    print a.autocommit
    c = a.cursor()
    c.execute("select 1")
    print c.fetchall()
    print "completed"
time.sleep(11000)
```

Then in mysql session run

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
|  10 | test | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |
| 310 | test | localhost | test | Sleep   |    8 |          | NULL             |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I only see 2 sessions, one is for my mysql command line, and another is from my python application.

In my python code, I open 100 connections, and didn't close any of them. But only the last connection is reached in the application, since variable a is re-assigned to a new connection in each loop. All other 99 connections is not reached in python. So I guess is that if the connection is not reached, then it will auto closed somehow. Any expert could confirm the behavior?

update:
after I added

```
print id(a)
```

to the function, then I found the id varied between 2 different values, that means it must use connection pool. I checked the document, but it said only when pass parameter of pool_name or pool_size will it creates connection pool. Not sure how is the connection pool is created, such as what's the connection name, and connection size of the pool created in my code.

Comment: Why dont you close the db before you go into sleep?

Comment: Yeah it is because garbage collection. It is not only for database connection but also for any variables which are not reachable will be auto deleted by garbage collector.